# How do I remove events from an array datasource in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to allow people to select multiple days. If they make a mistake, they can click the event to remove it.

Here's where I am:

```
  var eventArray = new Array();
  var cal = $('#new-show-calendar');
  cal.fullCalendar({
      height: 250
      ,events: eventArray
      ,dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var stringDate = date.toString();
        e = { title: "Some Title", start: stringDate }
        eventArray.push(e);
        cal.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', e );
      }
      ,eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        eventArray.splice(eventArray.indexOf(event), 1);
        cal.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', event._id );
      }
  })
```

This line gives semi-unpredictable results

```
cal.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', event._id );
```

I've tried rerenderEvents (which doesn't do anything) and a few other things. I'm trying to avoid cleaning out all the events then re-rendering each event individually for performance reasons.

I assume this is a bit of wonkiness around having a local, array-based datasource as opposed to a json source somewhere else.

**EDIT: This code (above) works as long as the view doesn't change. If I remove some things, then switch months, new events no longer persist on the calendar across views.**

How can I remove an event from the calendar?

Comment: where are semicolons?

Comment: They're not absolutely needed @vladkras (although ususally useful)

Comment: Yeah I was just banging out some proof of concept code for the sake of this question. I went and re-added the semicolons for posterity.

Comment: ok, I see, did you read this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ ?